# css - translate3d would cause element draggable in the mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

My dom structure and javascripts are like http://jsfiddle.net/vishl/wzPSF/

(I am using AngularJS to do the animation)

Everything works well in desktop computer.

But in the mobile device, when the translate3d animation triggle, with the `touchmove` event, the `wrapper` become draggable.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the translate3d occur, the document's width is not the origin width. It has become translateX + origin width.

So, the easiest way to fix this issue is, add the follow code to your css.

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```